# Countifs VBA to count non blank cells

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following VBA formula to count non blank cells in a range, plus some other conditions in other ranges. The part to count non blank cells is not working. This is the piece of code:

```
LAX(0) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("I:I"), "<>""", Range("AH:AH"), "LAX", Range("AG:AG"), ">=" & semanaI, Range("AG:AG"), "<=" & semanaF)
```

Are the first two arguments correct?

Comment: Ever since Excel 2007 there is a function called COUNTBLANK. Is that of any help?  https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTBLANK-function-6a92d772-675c-4bee-b346-24af6bd3ac22

Comment: No, because that's not the only condition that needs to be met

Comment: Apparently, the `COUNTIF` function supports wildcards: https://support.office.com/en-gb/article/COUNTIF-function-e0de10c6-f885-4e71-abb4-1f464816df34 There is also an example on the site which allows you to `Counts the number of cells containing any text[...]`. To ensure that at least one character is in a cell you can even look for the following wildcard combination: `*?*`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it by doing:

```
LAX(0) = Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(Range("I:I"), "<>" & "", Range("AH:AH"), "LAX", Range("AG:AG"), ">=" & semanaI, Range("AG:AG"), "<=" & semanaF)
```

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you need a little bit more handling with your conditional, because If a cell in any argument is an empty cell, **CountIfs treats it as a 0 value.**

(REFERENCE, BRO: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.worksheetfunction.countifs.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

So,

Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIfs( {range to evaluate criteria}, {criteria_1} ,{criteria_2},...)

do this:

```
Dim rCell as Range.Cells
Dim rRange as range

Set rRange = Range("I:I")

For Each rCell in rRange

    If { foo } Then
        'do stuff
    Elif { bar} 
        'do stuff
    Else { derp}
        'do stuff
    End If

Debug.Print rCell.Address, rCell.Value

Next rCell
```