# VBA code for Excel, looking for a count that doesn't not count an empty string

Tags: excel, vba, vba7

I'm trying to do a count of a column range that has values and empty strings returned by formulae.  There are empty strings as the formulae have not returned a value.  How do I count the returned values and not the empty strings? CountA is returning empty strings as well which I don't want.

I'm trying to use Countif but it's giving me the "reverse value" of what I'm looking for.  It seems to be counting the empty strings but not the returned values, as it were.

intCount = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("AC5:AC98"), "<>""")

I'm trying not to use a loop.

Comment: What about: WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("AC5:AC98"), ">0")

Comment: Doesn't work.  Comes back as zero.

Comment: `WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("AC5:AC98"), "<>" & "")`, see: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35705886/19353309)

Answer (score 0):

I figured out to do a sum where a total count less a function that counts the blanks which includes counting empty strings gives me the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is looking for cells which don't contain two quotation marks ("").

For finding non empty cells the literal is "<>". In your case

```
intCount = WorksheetFunction.CountIf(Range("AC5:AC98"), "<>")
```

If you need blank cells

```
intCount = WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Range("AC5:AC98"))
```

If you need non blank cells

```
intCount = Range("AC5:AC98").Count - WorksheetFunction.CountBlank(Range("AC5:AC98"))
```

Comment: Your code works for counting non-empty cells. If you put `=""` in one of the cells, the cell is no longer empty. Using your code, this cell will also be counted. OP doesn't want it counted.

Answer (score 0):

### Count Non-Blanks in a Single-Column Range

**VBA**

```vb
Sub CountNonBlanksInSingleColumnRange()

    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ActiveSheet ' improve!
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = ws.Range("AC5:AC98")
    
    Dim nbCount As Long: nbCount = rg.Rows.Count - Application.CountBlank(rg)
    
    MsgBox nbCount & " cells are not blank.", vbInformation

End Sub
```

**Excel**

```
=ROWS(AC5:AC98)-COUNTBLANK(AC5:AC98)
```

In Excel 'jargon', counts the cells that are not blank and don't contain *Nothing*.